# Which PHP String function to use?

Tags: php, string

Which string function can I use to strip everything after `-` ? The string is not predefined so `rtrim()` does not work.

> 9453-abcafaf3ceb895d7b1636ad24c37cb9f-100.png?1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the <strike>[`split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)</strike> [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function and the "-" character as the delimiter. It will return an array of strings. If you only care about information before the first dash, just use the zeroth index of the returned array.

edit: 
Sorry. After living in the python world for several months, split was the first thing that came to mind. `explode` is the correct function.

edit 2: 
`strip`, `lstrip`, and `rstrip` are meant to be used for trimming whitespace off the end(s) of a string.

Comment: Recommending a deprecated function? Hmmmm

Answer (score 4):

You could use [substr](http://php.net/substr) and [strpos](http://php.net/strpos):

```
$id = substr($path, 0, strpos($path, '-'));
```

Or alternatively [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$id = preg_replace('/(.*?)-.*/', '\1', $path);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the left portion of the string is always numeric, you can use PHP's auto type conversion and just add it to zero. (assuming you mean the first hyphen)

Try this:

`print 0 + '9453-abcafaf3ceb895d7b1636ad24c37cb9f-100.png?1'; //outputs 9453`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which dash? I would recommend using `explode` and just getting the array element for the string portion you want. Check it out: http://php.net/explode

Again, this will be very dependent on the amount of dashes in the string and may require additional logic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe he wants to get rid of the rightmost -. In this case you can use regex:

```
$s = '9453-abcafaf3ceb895d7b1636ad24c37cb9f-100.png?1';
$str = preg_replace('!-[^-]*$!', '', $s);

echo $str; // outputs 9453-abcafaf3ceb895d7b1636ad24c37cb9f
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be faster than preg_replace:

```
$str = '9453-abcafaf3ceb895d7b1636ad24c37cb9f-100.png?1';

$str = explode('-', $str);
array_pop($str);
$str = implode('-', $str) . '-';

// result = 9453-abcafaf3ceb895d7b1636ad24c37cb9f-
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude everything before the first hyphen and concatenate everything else, you could do this:

```
<?php
$str='9453-abcafaf3ceb895d7b1636ad24c37cb9f-100.png?1';

$str = explode('-', $str);
$count = count($str);

// So far we have the string exploded but we need to exclude
// the first element of the array and concatenate the others

$new = ''; // This variable will hold the concatenated string

for($i=1;$i<$count;++$i){
    $new.=$str[$i];
}

echo $new; // abcafaf3ceb895d7b1636ad24c37cb9f100.png?1
?>
```

So, basically, you loop through the elements and concatenate them as they were initially, but now we are skipping the first one.